# Android object animation not working smoothly

Tags: android, objectanimator

I am using ObjectAnimator to move the position of the RelativeLayout from center of the screen to above.The animation works on the RelativeLayout,but it does not move smoothly.It jumps between the start and end position.
Code:

```
 ObjectAnimator animY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(logolayout, "y", 350f);
                animY.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
               animY.setDuration(1500);
                animY.start();
```

Comment: Does your animation run smoothly if you exchange Relative Layout for e.g. a FrameLayout with an ImageView inside?

Answer (score 1):

Use ViewPropertyAnimator instead.

```
animate(view).y(350f).setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()).setDuration(1500).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the following:

```
animY.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
```